# Always set 'user' to be false, unless specified

Tags: cakephp

Whenever I am on my users homepage, by default the user prefix is set to true for any link. So if i am on users page and am trying to go to /contact. It will take me to /user/contacts. I have to do the following for the link to take to me to contact page.

```
echo $this->Html->link('Find out more',
  array(
    'controller' => 'contact',
    'action' => 'index',
    'user' => false
  ),
  array(
    'class' => 'btn btn-blue'
  )
);
```

Is there anyway i can set 'user' to always be false, and only set to true when i need it, as oppose to it always being true.

***EDIT***
Router code for the user prefix

```
Router::connect('/user', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'user' => true));
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post the code that directs you to /user/contacts ?

Comment: So if i am on my user homepage, then the code i have presented above but without the 'user' => false will direct me to /user/contacts.

Comment: how looks your router?, add ti question.

Comment: Please see edit above. Is thats what you are asking for?

Comment: @Salines any idea? Thanks